# How to deal with commas for decimal AND thousand separator

Tags: python, string, formatting, decimal-point

Due to reasons that are not important here, I have an excel sheet where my numbers have commas for decimal points as well as thousands separators. 
The only way to differentiate if the comma is supposed to be a decimal or a thousands separator, is the number of digits after the comma:

```
decimal = 7,29
thousands = 23,767,209
```

My approach, which works fine for my case, is to read in the numbers as strings and execute the following code:

```
strings = ["0", "87,390,112", "78", "9,27", "1"]
strings_new = []

for i in strings:
    if len(i) >= 3:
        # check if third last char is a comma --> decimal
        if i[-3] == ',':
            i = i[:-3] + '.' + i[-3 + 1:]              
    if len(i) >= 4:
        # check if fourth last char is a comma --> all commas are thousands
        if i[-4] == ',':
            i = i.replace(",", "")

    strings_new.append(i)

strings_new = [float(i) for i in strings_new]
```

And the output looks fine:

`strings_new = [0.0, 87390112.0, 78.0, 9.27, 1.0]`

Are there any special cases this code is missing that I haven't thought of? And is there maybe a more efficient way to deal with this problem?

Comment: South Africa? That's the only culture I know that uses this partially - it's official but people don't use it. Instead of trying to transform the string use eg `locale.atof` or `babel.parse_decimal` to parse the string using a specific culture's settings.

Comment: This is actually an 'official' way of representation somewhere in the World?! I assumed this was a fucked up version of one of the excel 'features' in combination with my data formatting...

Comment: there are no `fucked up version of one of the excel 'features'`. When you see `;` used as a list separator, it's because that's the actual list separator in your locale. South Africa uses comma for both thousand and decimal separators. India somehow groups large numbers in twos instead of threes. What looks strange to developers is how end users actually work

Comment: To put it another way, `Due to reasons that are not important here` those may be the most important reasons. If you know the problem is due to localization, it's often easy to find a way to handle the problem, and even handle different locales in the same program. You could tell people for example to put files into different folders by locale and use a different culture setting for each folder. Or you could use some indicator on the file name to pick the culture.

Comment: Another possibility is that you could "fix" the problem at the source - why read numbers from Excel as *text* when they are stored as decimals? Did the end users store them as text because they didn't know how to specify number formats in Excel? You could show them, they could get their job done faster *and* you'd get actual numbers

Comment: Since you did not think this was a legitimate locale, @sara, I think that reduces the possibility that your input spreadsheet is well formatted according to a locale, and increases the chance that it's some "$#@%ed" up excel "feature", IMO, because certainly there's things "$#@%ed" in microsoft world. They've been to court over it. And come out worse off. But maybe a more likely scenario is that the data has been badly typed. Either way, there's certainly no guarantees that excel is behaving well or your users are reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two cases:

1. If the decimal is only one digit: `100,1`. Use `i.rfind(',')` to get the comma position instead of hard-coding it with `-3`.
2. If it contains both conditions: `10,000,24`. It will slip through the second if-clause (`10,000.24`). Always running `i.replace(",", "")` without the if-clause should be fine.